# Join subquery inside a subquery when using count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to join a sub query count of months by counting the rows returned of another subquery.
My problem is I don't know if/how I can expose the REP_ID (with MONTH_COUNT) to join to my main query.

```
INNER JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS MONTH_COUNT
FROM
(
SELECT REP_ID, COUNT(MONTH(COMP_DT)) AS COUNT_
FROM dattbl_Case AS MONTH_
WHERE (CASE_TYPE=@CASE_TYPE) AND COMP_DT > DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()) AND COMP_DT <= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY MONTH(COMP_DT), REP_ID
) AS MONTH__
) AS MONTHS_
ON EXPIRE_.REP_ID=?
```

Comment: have you tried using WHERE instead of INNER JOIN like this: WHERE EXPIRE_.REP_ID = MONTH_.REP_ID ?

Comment: Now your only option is to join ON EXPIRE_.REP_ID= MONTHS_.MONTH_COUNT. Ask questions clearly!!

Comment: My question was why the sub query of the sub query was not exposed to the main query to join. The question was quite clear. See my answer and you will see I just didn't reference the proper sub query hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
INNER JOIN
(SELECT REP_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(COMP_DT)) AS COUNT_
 FROM dattbl_Case AS MONTH_
 WHERE CASE_TYPE = @CASE_TYPE AND COMP_DT > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND
       COMP_DT <= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) 
 GROUP BY REP_ID
) AS MONTHS_
ON EXPIRE_.REP_ID = MONTHS_.REP_ID
```

This formulation assumes that the months are all within the same year.  If you want counts greater than 12, you need to include the year as well as the month.

Comment: I was just not exposing/referencing the REP_ID through the parent queries. Thanks though.

Comment: @pcpimpster . . . I don't understand your comment.  Isn't this what you want to do?

Comment: Just ran your query and yes it works as well as my corrected query, yours is simpler actually. Thanks. I was too focused on the additional sub query I was using. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected solution. I just didn't expose the subquery to the parent subquery to then join to the main query.

```
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MONTH__.REP_ID, COUNT(*) AS MONTH_COUNT
FROM
(
SELECT MONTH_.REP_ID, COUNT(MONTH(COMP_DT)) AS COUNT_
FROM dattbl_Case AS MONTH_
WHERE (CASE_TYPE=@CASE_TYPE) AND COMP_DT > DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()) AND COMP_DT <= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(COMP_DT), REP_ID
) AS MONTH__
GROUP BY MONTH__.REP_ID 
) AS MONTHS_
ON EXPIRE_.REP_ID=MONTHS_.REP_ID
```